# c# How to render images properly?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

### Background

I am writing an app which copies the object of the clipboard when hitting `ctrl+c` or `print screen` so that you not only  have the current content but also "older" strings images files etc.

### More background

My app has **3 listboxes** and **1 picBox**. The PicBox is a preview window.
If the user double-clicks an image (*pasting it to the clipboard*) he'll get a preview (*so that he can assure it is the right one*).

### What I want to improve

I tested the preview and experienced some artifacts at the edges of the picBox:

[image: Artifacts]

**First row:** the original images (following called image 1/2/3).

**Second row:** the order I clicked the images. There are some artifacts in the second and third column.

**Third row:** if I click **image 1** and then **image 3**, I get the image you can see in **row 3 col 2**. **row3 col3** shows the same image but highlighted the artifacts.

The artifacts seems to be left overs from the first image, cause they are at the same position as the first image's "red lines"

The method I use is:

```
        Graphics grx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        grx.DrawImage(clipboardListImage[listBoxImg.SelectedIndex], new Rectangle      (new  Point(0,0), pictureBox1.Size));
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Have you tried using `new Point(1, 1)` instead of `new Point(0, 0)`? By the way, nicely constructed question! +1

Comment: But using (1,1) would mean, that the first row and first column aren't affected by the drawing event and I also think that it is no guarantee that the interpolation will work. And ty for the layout ;)

Comment: You're right. What about clearing the image first. You can use `grx.Clear(Color.White);` for example.

Comment: This would mean that if my new image has a red Pixel at the right edge and i am drawing on the white image. An interpolation between the new red pixel and the old white pixel would be applied if the image doesn't fit perfectly to the picBox. Depding how good it fits it could be red but also something like RGB(128,0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got a solution. If I am wrong pls correct me.

I am using imageAttributes and set the wrapmode to TileFlipXY.

```
        ImageAttributes imgattr = new ImageAttributes();
        imgattr.SetWrapMode(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
```

and use it in the drawing function.

```
grx.DrawImage(clipboardListImage[listBoxImg.SelectedIndex], new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), pictureBox1.Size),0,0,
            clipboardListImage[listBoxImg.SelectedIndex].Width, clipboardListImage[listBoxImg.SelectedIndex].Height,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgattr);
```

Not very handy but it seems to be working ;)